# Object.create alters console output of proto object in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log, object-create

I was playing around today when I noticed that some of my objects in Chrome's console were being displayed as `Object` instead of the constructor function name.

This was odd, so I boiled it down to the following code:

```
function Baz() {
    this.baz = true;
}
var b = new Baz();
var c = Object.create(b);
console.log(b); // why is b outputting with Object not Baz?
```

In the above code `b`, is not created via a `Object.create` and yet when logged it says Object. **I don't have a typo there, and mistakenly asking about c.** The log of b has been altered when I haven't even touched that object. Creating another instance `c`, should not alter `b`.

This has to be a Chrome bug right? Is there anyway to get Chrome to correctly report `Baz` here?

This is important for debugging purposes.

[image]

**UPDATE** Bug filed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=478522

Comment: chrome is right you are wrong

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @webduvet do you understand my question? Object.create is alerting what is being logged to the console for b. I'm not talking about c and the new object created.

Comment: @pbo well maybe that's the case,  perhaps if you were more explicit what you actually expect and what chrome gives you it might help :)

Comment: Are you reading my question? I'm asking why is Baz not being outputted. It's right there in my description.

Comment: You are expecting the constructor, but you are logging its instance.

Comment: well on my chrome is all as usual and expected.  b is show as `Baz {baz: true}`

Comment: Oh interesting on my Mac that's not the case. @Leo I'm expecting the instance but chrome names the instance with the constructor.

Comment: well maybe you meant to `console.log(c)` not `b` ?

Comment: @pbo I added a screenshot to your question, is that what you are talking about? If it's not please revert my edit.

Comment: @Leo Excellent! Thank you so much. That definitely helps show the issue more clearly :)

Comment: it does not change on my box.  Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)

Comment: @webduvet Looks like what I have above was introduced in v 42. If you update you will get the behavior I show above. Looks like Chrome IS wrong :)

Comment: I just have noticed the below updated answer. well spotted. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: This is indeed a regression between Chrome 41 and Chrome 42. It's being tracked here: http://crbug.com/478522

Chrome 41's output:
[image]

Chrome 42's output:

[image]

They've made improvements to syntax highlighting as you type in the dev tools and this probably broke. I've pinged a friend who is deeply involved with the dev tools. Nice find.

---

No. The problem you describe is very real.

Objects created with constructors will have their name displayed when logging them and generally better debugging experience in Chrome (and in node/io.js).

For this reason - I avoid `Object.create` for prototypical inheritance in my own code although I prefer it conceptually.

I think you understand this - but I still want to clarify for future readers. **Note that the inheritance still happens with the Object.create version** - the only difference is in how the object is *logged* and treated in the *debugger*.

Comment: What's odd is I'm not talking about the new object. The var b in my example was created solely via a constructor function. I don't see why creating another object alters what chrome outputs.

Comment: @pbo ` console.log(b)` logs `Baz {baz: true}`, and `console.log(c)` logs `Object {baz: true}` (although it _is_ a Baz, because it was created with Object.create and not a constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No, both log `Object {baz: true}`.

Comment: @Siguza then it's a bug, this is what Chrome does on my box: http://i.imgur.com/I9wbgry.png

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well here's mine: http://i.imgur.com/UxvadIy.png btw, Chrome 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit), Mac

Comment: I'm on Chrome 41 on Mac, lemme update to 42 and check real quick.

Comment: @Siguza sweet find, I can definitely reproduce this as a regression from Chrome 41 to Chrome 42 (On 64bit mac) I'll ping a friend who works on the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum I knew it was a bug :)

Comment: @pbo I owe you an update, this is [the related issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=339099) I've spoken to a very involved Googler about it and I've asked a friend to take a stab at a fix, if he doesn't I'll take a stab myself. Good find.